# Установочный пакет ASP.NET приложения с помощью WiX

Tags: asp.net, wix

Изучаю WiX - вроде понял азы - пакет обычного приложения создается без проблем. Однако необходимо создать пакет установки ASP.NET приложения, при этом должна присутствовать возможность - нахождения веб сервера (IIS) где устанавливается пакет, определения уже зарегистрированных веб-приложений, с возможностью установки в одной из них, либо создание новой. Аналогично и с app pool-ами - выборка из уже существующих либо создание новой.

В сети есть примеры данного действа - но несмотря на все попытки не срабатывают, либо падают с ошибкой. Копания в коде ни к чему не привели.

Может у кого-то есть действующий пример сабжа - либо ликбез на данную тему?